# symfony2 twig render, exception thrown

Tags: symfony, twig

So in my base template, I have: `{% render "EcsCrmBundle:Module:checkClock" %}`

Then I created the ModuleController.php...

```
<?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Ecs\CrmBundle\Entity\TimeClock;

class ModuleController extends Controller
{
    public function checkClockAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $today = time();
        $start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
        $entities = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock');
        $query = $entities->createQueryBuilder('tc')
                ->select('tc.in1, tc.out1, tc.in2, tc.out2, tc.in3, tc.out3')
                ->where('tc.noteBy = :user')
                ->andWhere('tc.daydate >= :start')
                ->setParameter('user', $user->getid())
                ->setParameter('start', $start)
                ->setMaxResults('1')
                ->getQuery();
         $entities = $query->getSingleResult();
         if (empty($entities)) {
            $ents = "clocked_out";
            $this->get('session')->set('clockedin', 'clocked_out');
         } else {
            for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
                if ($entities["in$i"] != NULL) {
                    $ents = "clocked_in";
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        $this->get('session')->set('nextclock', "out$i");
                    } else {
                        $x = $i+1;
                        $this->get('session')->set('nextClock', "out$x");
                    }
                    if ($entities["out$i"] != NULL) {
                        $ents = "clocked_out";
                        $x = $i+1;
                        $this->get('session')->set('nextclock', "in$x");
                    }
                    if ($entities["out3"] != NULL) {
                        $ents = "day_done";
                    }
                }
            }
         }
        return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:Module:topclock.html.twig', array(
            'cstat' => $ents,
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem is, if there is nothing in the database for the specific day for the specific user yet.. i keep getting:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.") in ::base.html.twig at line 161.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception: NoResultException »
```

I know it has something to do with the fact that is no 'result' from the database...  but isn't that what i've accomplished by having the `if (empty($entities)) {` ??  I have no clue to fix it...  any help appreciated...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace:

```
$entities = $query->getSingleResult();
```

With

```
$entity = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

If you look in Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery you will see that getSingleResult expects one and only one results. 0 will through an exception.

I looked at your code a bit more closely and it looks like you actually expect an array of entities.  in which case use:

```
$entities = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Nice!  I was dealing with an issue much like this and you solved it for me..  +1 for the OP and +1 for Cerad!