# Symfony 2.0 => Symfony 2.1: Twig_Error_Runtime - Notice: Array to string conversion in Translator.php line 130

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I have an error while upgrading my symfony application from version 2.0.19 to 2.1.8.

I have just submit a Contact person form and I have this error:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php line 130") in "AppBundle:Contact:index.html.twig".

at Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array(entities))
```

Note that if I refresh the page, there is no error.

Any Help please, I am becoming crazy...

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Can this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985785/symfony2-twig-render-exception-thrown ? If not, show us some code :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tomorrow I Will givr you all thé error because unfortunately it doesnt help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, I have found the solution :-)

It's because I try to translate a non string value. The **flashbag** value is NOW an array not a string.

Hope it will help some guy :-)

Sam